# Error: waiting for creation of MsSql Database - Terraform failure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have had to re-develop my pipeline for building out my infrastructure to use local agent pools and change Ubuntu code to windows (PowerShell code).

I am now in the position where I am building out my infrastructure and it failing on the most basic of tasks.

I have created my SQL Server and that seems to be OK. I have also got my logging system infra done OK too, but I am really struggling on building out a DB on my SQL Server.

At the most basic here is my code. Server build OK.

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "main" {
  name                         = local.sqlServerName
  resource_group_name          = local.resourceGroupName
  location                     = var.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  minimum_tls_version          = "1.2"
  administrator_login          = var.sql_administrator_login
  administrator_login_password = var.sql_administrator_login_password
  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator" "main" {
  server_name         = azurerm_mssql_server.main.name
  resource_group_name = local.resourceGroupName
  login               = local.sql_ad_login
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = local.object_id 
}


resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "main" {
  name                = var.sql_firewall_rule
  resource_group_name = local.resourceGroupName
  server_name         = azurerm_mssql_server.main.name
  start_ip_address    = "0.0.0.0"
  end_ip_address      = "0.0.0.0"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "main" {
  name                        = "${local.raptSqlDatabaseName}-${var.environment}"
  server_id                   = azurerm_mssql_server.main.id
  min_capacity                = 0.5
  max_size_gb                 = 100
  zone_redundant              = false
  collation                   = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  sku_name                    = "GP_S_Gen5_2"
  auto_pause_delay_in_minutes = 60
  create_mode                 = "Default"

}
```

I get an error saying:

> Error: waiting for creation of MsSql Database "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-Prod" (MsSql Server Name "xxx-xxx-xxx-prod" / Resource Group "rg-xxx-xxx-xxx"): Code="InternalServerError" Message="An unexpected error occured while processing the request.

Before I had to design it all in PS and not bash and use local pool, I never had a problem and this worked fine.

I found this but it's saying the correct error but nothing else seems correct. It is odd because I can build up my other infra fine in the same main.tf file.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/13194

I am also noticing that Terraform output is not working:

Here is my output file:

```
output "sql_server_name" {
  value = azurerm_mssql_server.main.fully_qualified_domain_name
}

output "sql_server_user" {
  value = azurerm_mssql_server.main.administrator_login
}

output "sql_server_password" {
  value = azurerm_mssql_server.main.administrator_login_password
  sensitive = true
}

#output "cl_sql_database_name" {
#  value = azurerm_mssql_database.cl.name
#}

#output "rapt_sql_database_name" {
#  value = azurerm_mssql_database.rapt.name
#}

output "app_insights_instrumentation_key" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.main.instrumentation_key
}
```

Is there any chance this is linked?

Comment: I tested the same code with azurerm latest version and it got successfully deployed

Comment: yes this is the whole code i am using

Comment: Does anyone else have any advice ? Also the terraform output is not showing after i translated everything from Bash to PS - could this have an impact on why its not working as it should

Comment: Checking the failed deployment in the resource group _might_ have a more detailed error message. Terraform should be platform agnostic for the same version, if you run the `terraform plan` in both the PS and Bash versions do you get the same output? Can you also clarify which output is not showing? Is it the `terraform output`?

Comment: @PeteP yes terraform output is completely blank... nothing in failed deployments in azure

Comment: Hmm. The "Error: waiting on creation" message suggests it's timing out waiting for the Azure side to respond, which would show in the Deployments for the RG. Since that's not happening then it isn't getting that far. At this point I'd temporarily set the TF_LOG env var to DEBUG and look for 4xx errors in the huge output.

Comment: @PeteP - I have created the environment variable and errors are showing... but absolutlely nothing more than my inital error.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT - i have an outputs.tf file and its not showing that since I have changed it from bash to ps

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT outputs file added

Comment: So the `terraform output` command gives an output in Bash but not in PS? This suggests that the PS version doesn't have access to the `terraform.tfstate` file so it thinks no resources exist. Check that the new agent pool has access to the backend where the remote state is stored. If you run `terraform state list` in Bash and PS do they show the same resources?

Answer (score 0):

Please use ***latest terraform version*** i.e. `1.1.13` and ***azurerm-provider*** i.e. `2.92.0` as ***there were some bugs in previous Azure API version which resulted in 500 Error Code which has been fixed in the recent versions as mentioned in this*** ***[`GitHub Issue`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/7999)*** . Only after a ***successful apply*** , you ***get the output*** otherwise it won't get stored if there is an error.

**I tested the same code with latest versions on both PowerShell and Bash as below :**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
locals {
  resourceGroupName="ansumantest"
  sqlServerName="ansumantestsql"
  sql_ad_login="sqladmin"
  object_id= data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  raptSqlDatabaseName="ansserverdb"
}
variable "location" {
  default="eastus"
}
variable "sql_administrator_login" {
  default="4dm1n157r470r"
}
variable "sql_administrator_login_password" {
  default="4-v3ry-53cr37-p455w0rd"
}
variable "sql_firewall_rule" {
  default="ansumantestfirewall"
}
variable "environment" {
  default="test"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "main" {
  name                         = local.sqlServerName
  resource_group_name          = local.resourceGroupName
  location                     = var.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  minimum_tls_version          = "1.2"
  administrator_login          = var.sql_administrator_login
  administrator_login_password = var.sql_administrator_login_password
}

resource "azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator" "main" {
  server_name         = azurerm_mssql_server.main.name
  resource_group_name = local.resourceGroupName
  login               = local.sql_ad_login
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = local.object_id 
}


resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "main" {
  name                = var.sql_firewall_rule
  resource_group_name = local.resourceGroupName
  server_name         = azurerm_mssql_server.main.name
  start_ip_address    = "0.0.0.0"
  end_ip_address      = "0.0.0.0"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "main" {
  name                        = "${local.raptSqlDatabaseName}-${var.environment}"
  server_id                   = azurerm_mssql_server.main.id
  min_capacity                = 0.5
  max_size_gb                 = 100
  zone_redundant              = false
  collation                   = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  sku_name                    = "GP_S_Gen5_2"
  auto_pause_delay_in_minutes = 60
  create_mode                 = "Default"
}
```

`Output.tf`

```
output "sql_server_name" {
  value = azurerm_mssql_server.main.fully_qualified_domain_name
}

output "sql_server_user" {
  value = azurerm_mssql_server.main.administrator_login
}

output "sql_server_password" {
  value = azurerm_mssql_server.main.administrator_login_password
  sensitive = true
}
output "cl_sql_database_name" {
  value = azurerm_mssql_database.main.name
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated Terraform to latest version didn't really help. I turned on logging with TF_LOGS (env variable in Terraform).

Watching the activity logs in the resource group and I noticed it was building the DB server and then there was an error with AAD and then the DB Server build failed after that. So I removed the AAD work in my main.tf - then I reran the pipeline then it worked fine.